# Blocking specific application on the iis

Tags: iis

Is there a away to block the access to my website from specific application or better to only allow one. In the logs i can see what application was used for the access of the site. So basicaly iis can differ wahat application were been used.

Answer (score 0):

I have achived this with the HTTP Rewrite Module provided by microsoft.